# need help understanding this transformation step in Riccati equation to Lyapunov equation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-control, lyapunov-functions

In this note [Discrete LQR note](https://faculty.washington.edu/chx/teaching/ucb-me233/UCB_ME233_2_DT_LQ.pdf), I am not understanding the transition from equation (4) to (5) on page 14.

In particular, I don't get this step:

$$
(A-BK_{s})^{\top}{P_s}(A-BK_{s}) + 2A^{\top}{P_{s}}BK_{s} - K_{s}^{\top}B^{\top}P_{s}BK_{s} + C^{\top}C - K^{\top}(R + B^{\top}PB)K \\
= (A-BK_{s})^{\top}{P_s}(A-BK_{s}) + C^{\top}C + K_{s}^{\top}RK_{s}
$$
What is the trick used here?

Comment: $Q=C^TC$, and the rest is just grind. Note how $K_s$ is defined.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the answer? I know how $K_s$ is defined, and have substituted it to the first equation but they do not seem to match.

Comment: Keep grinding. Note that $(R+B^T P_s B) K_s = B^T P_s A$ and so $K_s^T B^T P_s A =  K_s^T (R+B^T P_s B) K_s $. Similarly for $A^TP_s B K_s$.

Comment: LQR/LQG/Kalman stuff is pure grind.

Comment: Thank you a lot, finally seeing it!